# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in javascript but idk why

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to test a html,css,javascript code but it don't work and I don't know why
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLBZB.jpg)

Make a random name winner with personnalized input name and pop in the screen the winner of the random system.

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery not imported or loaded correctly..

From cdn:

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Insert this tag befor your custom script..

Comment: It solve it thx but some other problem pop I will see by myself and repost if I don't find the problem but thx :)